# Структура бд в firebase

Tags: firebase, nosql

Плохо понимаю, как организовать высокоскоростную структуру в firebase.
С помощью Alias производится поиск нужного имени.

```
Name: Victor
Alias: ["Victor","Vitya","Виктор","Витя"]
```

Но мне кажется поиск по таким документам может занимать большое время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорость извлечения данных **Firestore** не зависит от количества данных. Скорость извлечение одного документа из коллекции в 100 документов, будет равна скорости извлечения из коллекции размером в 100,000,000.

> Queries scale with the size of
>   your result set, not the size of your data set, so you'll get the same
>   performance fetching 1 result from a set of 100, or 100,000,000.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603205/queries-scale-with-the-size-of-your-result-set-not-the-size-of-your-data-set

Так что твоя структура уже должна быть достаточно скоростной.

Немного о массивах в Firestore:
 https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html